# Create video from images and audio with varying image durations using FFMPEG?

Tags: terminal, ffmpeg, video-streaming

What I want to do:

I've x amount of images png/jpg, and I want to show them for varying amount of duration, some longer, and some shorter amount of time.

- a1.jpg 1st photo stays for 3 seconds
- a2.png stays for 10 seconds
- a3.jpg stays till end of audio

Video should be as long as audio.mp3

this is my code so far after reading documentation, not sure what's wrong, I get corrupt video with no sound and only shows last image.

Also would like to center images if possible.

```
ffmpeg -y \
  -loop 1 -t 1 -i a1.jpg \
  -loop 1 -t 1 -i a2.jpg \
  -loop 1 -t 4 -i a3.jpg \
  -loop 1 -t 1 -i a4.png \
  -loop 1 -t 1 -i a5.png \
  -i audio.mp3 \
  -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy video.mp4
```

try

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 15 \
  -loop 1 -t 1 -i a1.jpg \
  -loop 1 -t 1 -i a2.jpg \
  -loop 1 -t 4 -i a3.jpg \
  -loop 1 -t 1 -i a4.png \
  -loop 1 -t 1 -i a5.png \
  -i audio.mp3 \
  -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy \
  -filter_complex " \
  [0]setdar=16/9[a1],[a1]scale=720x406[a];[1]setdar=16/9[b1],[b1]scale=720x406[b];[2]setdar=16/9[c1],[c1]scale=720x406[c];[3]setdar=16/9[d1],[d1]scale=720x406[d];[4]setdar=16/9[e1],[e1]scale=720x406[e]; 
  [a][b][c][d][e]concat=n=5,format=yuv420p[v],[v]scale=720x406[v1],[v1]setdar=16/9[v2]" \
  -map "[v2]" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basic template is

```
ffmpeg -y \
  -loop 1 -t 1 -i a1.jpg \
  -loop 1 -t 1 -i a2.jpg \
  -loop 1 -t 4 -i a3.jpg \
  -loop 1 -t 1 -i a4.png \
  -loop 1 -i a5.png \
  -i audio.mp3 \
  -filter_complex "concat=n=5" -shortest \
  -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac video.mp4
```

The `t` specification for each image sets its duration. The `t` for the last image should be omitted if you want the video to last till the audio ends.

I use the concat filter to join all video inputs. Good practice is to label which inputs the concat filter will join, but if unspecified, the filter will grab the first N `-i` inputs, where N is the value set in the concat filter. All images must have the same resolution and aspect ratio.

Your given command copies the audio but MP3, although allowed, isn't standard in MP4, and some players, like Quicktime, will not play the file, so I've changed it to AAC.

---

For images of unequal sizes, change filter_complex to

```
"[0]scale=W:H:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=W:H:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[i0];
 [1]scale=W:H:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=W:H:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[i1];
 [2]scale=W:H:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=W:H:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[i2];
 [3]scale=W:H:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=W:H:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[i3];
 [4]scale=W:H:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=W:H:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[i4];
 [i0][i1][i2][i3][i4]concat=n=5"
```

W and H should be replaced with numerical values of target video width and height.

Comment: would it possible to scale each image to have height of resolution defined. So say i set resolution to 720/460 ... and if any image height is lower than that then scale it to 460. Having same height and width would require some other operation to make them all like that

Comment: Well, same resolution - W and H - is required, whether done inside or outside ffmpeg.

Comment: Can I assume the first image is the target resolution?

Comment: Ok yea that can be assumed

Comment: usually if image is shorter it's background is filled with black

Comment: That's padding. Do you want to rescale or pad image?

Comment: rescale until height is same of smaller images

Comment: say image is exactly resolution no problem, image is taller, than make it fit would need padding on left and right, is shorter than would need to rescale... upon rescaling might not need padding if aspect ratio are good otherwise padding

Comment: text method doesn't complain about different sizes

Comment: Yes, but output will not be widely compatible.

Comment: I've this ugly command which is sort of working now see edit

Comment: thanks a ton, been at it for like 5 hours, what's a good way to learn this tool.

Comment: Regular use and the docs.